# Prove that the probability of getting an even number is a strictly decreasing by $\lambda$

Tags: calculus, probability

Would like to get some ideas for this problem, based on the information I have. The question:

"The probability of generating a certain number $X$ is Poisson Distributed $X \in Poi(\lambda$). Suppose $\lambda$ is increasing by an arbitrary amount everytime you generate a new number X. Show that the probability of getting an even number is strictly decreasing with $\lambda$"

I'm not sure if I understand the question fully, but I wanted to test if this was true for $2$ an even number, if $\lambda$ increases:

$P(X = 2 | \lambda) = \displaystyle \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^2}{2!}$

Taking the derivative $\frac{d}{d\lambda}$ yields: $\displaystyle \frac{-e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{2}+e^{-\lambda}2\lambda}{2!}$. This indicate that the function is not strictly decreasing for all $\lambda$. It's only strictly decreasing when $\lambda > 2$.

Am I mis-reading the question or what's going on?

Comment: You need to sum all X=0,2,4,6,... not just consider X=2.

Comment: Are the words "getting an even number is strictly decreasing" meaningful?

Comment: Sorry, I clarified it. It's solved below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** The quantity $P(X = 2 \mid \lambda)$ is the probability of getting exactly $2$. The probability that the sum is *some* even number is

$$\sum_{\textrm{$k$ even}} P(X = k \mid \lambda)
= \sum_{l = 0}^\infty P(X = 2l \mid \lambda)
= \sum_{l = 0}^\infty \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^{2 l}}{(2l)!}
= e^{-\lambda}  \sum_{l = 0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{2 l}}{(2l)!} .$$

> **Additional hint** The series in the rightmost expression is the Taylor series for a common function.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It becomes $e^{-\lambda} \cdot cosh(\lambda)$ which is a strictly decreasing function. It didn't occur to me that I had to sum all the numbers in order to get the correct answer, I thought it was enough checking any even number.

Comment: Like you write, $P(X = k \mid \lambda)$ has a sole (global) maximum at $\lambda = k$.